# Connect to Cassandra 3.0.3 (using 9042) from SoapUI

Tags: cassandra, soapui, thrift, cassandra-3.0

I want to connect to Cassandra DB from SoapUI via JDBC step. And want to make different queries, using cql, as well.
**Note:** I read through existed here answers on similar questions, but they did not help in result.

Pre-condition: Cassandra DB (Cassandra version 3.0.3), on server with IP smth like 10.x.x.x, port 9042

Done: I added following jars to `<soapui>../bin/ext`:

```
- cassandra-all-3.9
- cassandra-clientutil-3.9
- cassandra-jdbc-1.2.5
- cassandra-thrift-3.9
- libthrift-0.9.3
- slf4j-api-1.7.7
- thrift-0.6.1
```

In SoapUI, in configuration, I configured:

```
Driver : org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver
Connection String : jdbc:cassandra://10.x.x.x:9042/profilename
```

But trying to test connection - I receive just

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: 
Read a negative frame size (-2080374784)
```

Question: how to fix this, to establish connection, and to make queries to DB?

Comment: You realise that `cassandra-all` includes the Cassandra server itself?

Comment: thanks, will redo jar list.

Comment: Do you have any idea what you're doing, or are you just adding random versions of random jars that you find?

Comment: Im just following already given answers for similar topics.

Comment: You're following [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22659506/476716)? That has some very bad and/or out-of-date answers. I might write a better one later today.

Comment: yep, that one and similar. thanks for Your help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39985140/476716

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cassandra Read a negative frame size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23249591/cassandra-read-a-negative-frame-size)

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be trying to connect the rpc (thrift) client to the native (CQL) port.

By default, 9042 should be the native port and 9160 the rpc port. These may have been changed: look in the server's [cassandra.yaml](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.x/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml.html) and find what has been configured for `native_transport_port` and/or `rpc_port`.

Bear in mind that thrift/rpc has been deprecated since Cassandra 2.x and you should be using CQL where possible.

Comment: Thanks, will do. Besides, checked from DataStax - works ok (queries, etc); in DataStax connection added via 9042

Comment: If this JDBC driver uses thrift instead, then you need to use port 9160.

Comment: Checked in yaml, on server (I have no rights to change there anything, so just info): native_transport_port: 9042; rpc_port: 9160; //////continue researching, thanks for initial advices.

Comment: So did you switch you connection string to 9160 or not?

Comment: yes, I changed, and seems connection established. But no results on same cql query(via SoapUI), which successfully returns results in DataStax.

Comment: seems I have next error: "could not init org.apache.casssandra.cql.jdbc.ColumnDecoder". Googling jar for that...

Comment: Well you can't run CQL over a thrift connection.